# Number one Eq. with (number+a,b) in an Eq. array?

Tags: equations, numbering, line-numbering

I want to number two equations on one line of an equation array in the form of (number a, b), here the "number" should be the line number. Please see the following code, I try to achieve it with `\eqno`, but Latex keeps showing me

> You can't use `\eqno` in math mode.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq1} & a+b+c=0,\\
\label{eq2} & d+e+f=0,\\
\label{eq3} & m+n = 0, \quad s+t=0, \eqno{(\theequation{\text{a},\text{b}})}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely I do not understand the question, you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}  a+b+c&=0,\\
\label{eq2}  d+e+f&=0,\\
\label{eq3}  m+n &= 0, \quad s+t=0, \tag*{(\theequation{\text{a},\text{b}})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and let me know if this is what you want. I have a hard time understanding what that could be good for.

Perhaps you are looking for something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}  a+b+c&=0,\\
\label{eq2}  d+e+f&=0,\\
\label{eq3}  m+n &= 0, \quad s+t=0,\stepcounter{equation} \tag*{(\theequation{\text{a},\text{b}})}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\label{eeq1}  a+b+c&=0,\\
\label{eeq2}  d+e+f&=0,\\
\label{eeq3}  m+n &= 0, \quad s+t=0,\stepcounter{equation} \tag*{(\theequation{\text{a},\text{b}})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jsxs Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions). There are reasons why it's advantageous to use align.

Comment: thanks! You have already resolved my question well with your second answer. So, to achieve this special aim we can only use `align` instead of `eqnarray`?

Comment: could you please check your link again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jsxs I'm so sorry, something went wrong. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/121799) is hopefully the correct link. (If you're interested in the equivalent of `\lefteqn`, use the `\MoveEqLeft` from the mathtools package, and if you are in the same minority like me who likes the spaces around equality signs in eqnarray, put extra spaces, but don't tell David Carlisle ;-)